# "Cannot convert 'float' to float**" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

I have written samples from microphone input into a `Float32` array, and now I want to turn that array of samples into a WAV file.

[Apparently a good way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231856/how-to-write-array-of-float-values-to-audio-file-in-core-audio) is to use a utility class from [the DIRAC library](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html), as its `EAFWrite` class has a `writeFloats` method that should do the trick.

When I call the EAFWrite's writeFloats method I get a "Cannot convert 'float' to float**" error. Here's the call:

`[mWriter writeFloats:128 fromArray:mySession];`

The array was initialised thus:
`Float32 mySession[10000000] = {0};`

What do you think is wrong? Is this a problem about pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peek at the `writeFloats:fromArray:` source code (it's included in the library, doncha kno) reveals that the `data` parameter should actually be an array of array pointers, with one array pointer per channel.  Presumably you specified one channel in some previous message to `mWriter`, so now you can just do this:

```
Float32 *channelsData[1] = { mySession };
[mWriter writeFloats:128 fromArray:channelsData];
```

or if you want to get really tricky:

```
[mWriter writeFloats:128 fromArray:(Float32 *[]){ mySession }];
```

Comment: Just heard from Stephan at DIRAC, he would agre with rob mayoff. I'll paste his answer: `writeFloats` expects a two dimensional array. In case of mono data this would be declared as

`float **data = new float*[1];`
`data[0] = new float[numFrames];`

Then you can fill it with the actual data like so:

`for (long s=0; s<numFrames; s++)`
`data[0][s] = micInputArray[s];`

Comment: Zero denotes that it is the first channel. 

The reason for this is that `-writeFloats` supports an arbitrary number of channels. In case of only one channel this looks overly complicated, but in case of multiple channels it's a common and very handy channel layout.